# Does str.length() takes o(n)?

Tags: java, string

I am a bit confused as to why an array length is a field and a String length is a function. does it mean that by using str.length() I traverse through all the chars of the String and return the count ?

Comment: You could check the source: [`String#length`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/String.java#String.length%28%29)

Comment: No you don't traverse. String keeps an array and it just returns its length. As to why string has a length method, it's because String is a class and not a primitive